# Questions with interactivePopGestureRecognizer when keyboard shown

Tags: objective-c, ios7, keyboard

[This is Screenshot](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-vpAzSRkfy9A/Up3LBG1ICYI/AAAAAAAAALM/1x2tiqXQBgE/w629-h598-no/%25E8%259E%25A2%25E5%25B9%2595%25E5%25BF%25AB%25E7%2585%25A7+2013-12-03+%25E4%25B8%258B%25E5%258D%25882.42.24.png)

In View B, When keyboard is shown and pop viewController to View A with interactivePopGestureRecognizer, the keyboard is still stay here :(

How can let keyboard move with view B ?
(like iMessage or Facebook Messenger)

ps: I'm try to get keyboard view and add to self.view, it's useful, but i think it's not a good way.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardDidShown)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
```

and

```
- (void)keyboardDidShown
{
    UIView * keyboardView = self.textView.inputAccessoryView.superview;
    [self.view addSubview: keyboardView];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

https://github.com/cotap/TAPKeyboardPop

This is lightweight category that listens `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` gesture and animating keyboard accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't add keybordView to the view. If you want to show keyboard for your UITextField/UITextView you call becomeFirstResponder on that object. In your example it should be:

```
[self.textView becomeFirstResponder];
```

If you want to hide keyboard you call:

```
[self.textView  resignFirstResponder];
```

And if you want to hide your keyboard before you dismiss your ViewA you should call it in the beginning of your interactivePopGestureRecognizer when you start animation to show ViewB.
Hope it help.

//EXTENDED

I don't know why you are trying to add accessoryView as a subview to your view

```
- (void)keyboardDidShown
{
    UIView * keyboardView = self.textView.inputAccessoryView.superview;
    [self.view addSubview: keyboardView];
}
```

And I don't understand why do you use notification centre.
The functionality that the keyboard stay when you dismissed the view (as iMessage app) is a standard functionality.
Just use

```
[self.textView becomeFirstResponder];
```

when you want to show the keyboard and don't call

```
[self.textView  resignFirstResponder];
```

when you pop your view controller. iOS does the job for you.

Comment: Sorry maybe I didn't convey clearly. I know how to show/hide keyboard, and after test i find it will send UIKeyboardWillHideNotification automatically when ViewA pop to ViewB , but keyboard didn't hide

Comment: I think this can happened because you add keyboardView as a subview to your view. Try replace it with [self.textView becomeFirstResponder];

Comment: No, add keyboardView to self.view is a try, not reason

Comment: After keyboard shown and textField/textView have inputAccessoryView, textView.inputAccessoryView.superview will be keyboardView, so add it to my view.

Comment: Thanks for your patience :)
I take a screenshot, hope it can convey my question.

https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-vpAzSRkfy9A/Up3LBG1ICYI/AAAAAAAAALM/1x2tiqXQBgE/w629-h598-no/%25E8%259E%25A2%25E5%25B9%2595%25E5%25BF%25AB%25E7%2585%25A7+2013-12-03+%25E4%25B8%258B%25E5%258D%25882.42.24.png

Comment: Ok I have your point now. Can I ask why are you trying to do this. In your ViewB keyboard is connected to text field but if you move it to ViewA the keyboard will be useless.

Comment: Oh! I don't want to do that. I hope I can do the same with iMessage, but I can't, I always got the results on right screen shoot.

Comment: Instead of add the keyboardView to self.view try add it to superview.